# template function argument is undefined?

Tags: c++, templates

In https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/aten/src/ATen/native/cpu/MaxPoolKernel.cpp#L468, it calls

```
cpu_max_pool<scalar_t, scalar_t>(output, indices, input, kW, kH, dW, dH, padW, padH, dilationW, dilationH);
```

where `cpu_max_pool` is a template function defined towards the top of the file, but `scalar_t` isn't defined in the calling function `max_pool2d_kernel_impl`?

`scalar_t` seems to be a template parameter in some other functions in this file, such as, `cpu_max_pool_backward_channels_last`, but not for `max_pool2d_kernel_impl`. So how is `scalar_t` being defined here?

Comment: This is inside a macro invocation. It is probably declared inside that macro.

Comment: @user17732522 the macro is defined here: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/aten/src/ATen/Dispatch.h#L291
I don't think I see how the macro is introducing the `scalar_t`?

Comment: This macro uses `AT_PRIVATE_CASE_TYPE` which uses `AT_PRIVATE_CASE_TYPE_USING_HINT` and at least introduces the token `scalar_t` into it.